# Convert Spring @RequestBody JSON object to map Java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm creating a rest endpoint whose RequestBody will be a JSON object:

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ValidateRequest
@ApiOperation(value = "updateDetails", nickname = "updateDetails")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = responseVO.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})

public @Valid
    PortalResponseVO updateDetails( @RequestBody Object JSONObj){
    ...
    }
```

My Request JSON would look something like

```
{
  name: "name1",
  description: "updating details by env",
  "env" : {
    "env1" : {
        "envName" : "envName1",
        "changeDesc" : "description1"
    },
    "env2" : {
         "envName" : "envName2",
        "changeDesc" : "description2"
    }
  }
 }
```

I want to map the JSON object to a Java Map object so I can use the details without having to create an object class for it.  However, since some fields are strings, and some are nested maps, I'm a little unsure about how to parse through the Object.  I tried using `HashMap<String, Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSONObj, HashMap.class);` but everytime I try to access a field like `String name = JSONObj.get("name")` I get the error `incompatible types: java.util.Map cannot be converted to java.lang.String`

**EDIT**

I have since changed my code to:

```
public @Valid
PortalResponseVO updateDetails( @RequestBody Map<String, Object>t JSONObj){

  String name = (String) JSONObj.get("name");
  String desc = (String) JSONObj.get("description");

  Map<String, Object> env = (Map<String, Object>) JSONObj.get("env");
  Map<String, String> env1 = (Map<String, String>) env.get("env1");
  Map<String, String> env2 = (Map<String, String>) env.get("env2");
}
```

I've compiled it and it seems to compile just fine, but I'm wondering will this work?  The data structure is static, besides the names and descriptions, so is it okay to force caste the objects like that?

Comment: JSONObj is of type Object. So JSONObj.get("name") can't compile. Post the actual code, and the complete and exact error you get.

Comment: @JBNizet I added some code that compiles correctly, but I want to know if it will work.

Comment: Test it, and you'll know.

Comment: @JBNizet Haha, true, but it's always nice to know if something seems correct before you deploy :)